# What is the maximum length of html textbox

Tags: asp.net, html

can anyone help me with the length of maximum characters that can be contain in a normal HTML text box....

Comment: Why do you ask? Questions like this are usually a flag that there is a design issue.

Comment: you must be a spammer, I've never run out of characters in a HTML textbox unless the website imposes additional restrictions using Javascript

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I was researching this issue today for a legitimate reason.

The E-Commerce platform Magento is a powerful and awesome piece of software. However it has a few quirky pieces of code. One of these quirks is in the product selection and sorting list when managing a category. 

There's a hidden field with a list of the products and sort orders separated by a semi-colon. A thousand products easily exceed the maximum field length causing annoying bugs.

This is obviously a design issue, but it helps to know these limitations for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As to the HTML side, when the `maxlength` attribute is not specified, then the maximum length of the input value is unlimited. However, if you're sending the request as `GET` instead of `POST`, then the limit will depend on the webbrowser and webserver used. The HTTP 1.1 specification even warns about this, here's an extract of [chapter 3.2.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1):

> *Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths
>   above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy
>   implementations might not properly support these lengths.*

As to the webbrowsers, the practical limit is in Firefox about 8KB, in Opera about 4KB and in IE and Safari about 2KB. So the total length of all inputs should not exceed this if you want a succesful processing. As to the webservers, most have a configureable limit of 8KB. When the limit is exceeded, then it will often just be truncated, but some webservers may send a [HTTP 414 error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.15).

When you're sending the request as `POST`, then the limit depends on the server config. Often it's around 2GB. When it's exceeded, the server will often return a [HTTP 500 error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1).

Answer (score 5):

Default `maxlength` is unlimited for a `<input type='text'/>`.  You may optionally provide this value to constrain input (but there's no guarantees the browser will enforce the rule).

A `<textarea>` does not support a `maxlength` so unlimited characters are accepted for input.

(ref: https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/HTMLPlus/htmlplus_41.html)

**RE:** Long string breaking during submit

There can be a maximum size to the amount of data submitted from a `form` when using the method `get` (the default if not specified).  It's only a can because many browsers allow many more characters now.  If you use a `form` with the `post` method, there is no maximum to the amount of data submitted.

Comment: Textarea doesn't support this attribute. You would have to bring some JS in.

Comment: thanks for the information i just wanted to know whether there is a limit for text box, ie if i pass a long string through it i don't want the string to break due to insufficient length

Comment: @BalusC true that... I'll rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML4, [the `maxlength` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-maxlength) is only supported on the `input` element. HTML5 extends this to allow it [on `textarea` as well](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-textarea-element). A [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/dYzsX/1/) works in Firefox 4 and WebKit, but not Firefox 3 or Opera. If you need support for HTML4, use JavaScript to manually limit the length.