# HTML Field for 96,004 Characters

Tags: asp.net, html, input, textarea

I'm writing a small asp app to query a server.  In order to query the script posts 2 values.  One is an identifier of the user, and the second contains encrypted data.

I don't need to decrypt the data, but the user has to be able to paste a string thats 96,004 characters long (or upload a txt file containing it).

I standard html textarea or input only allows for 30,468 characters.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Related: [What is the maximum length of html textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969650/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-html-textbox)

Comment: What browser are you using and what error, if any, are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a text area actually chopping off characters at the 30K mark.  It sounds like either the server or the browser has a post size limitation.

You can change the request size limitation on the server by changing your web.config to something like:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Note that the length is in KB.  So the above actually limits it to 4MB.

Comment: I don't have access to the server to change that config.  And I think you are correct, it may be a browser limitation

Comment: I just looked up the default for .net.  It's 4MB.  So unless the server operator limited it down, it has to be a browser issue.  If I had to take a guess I'd say your using Safari.

Comment: In order to get around this, if you have access to change the code, get rid of the text box they use for copy/pasting the data and instead use a file upload.

Comment: I'm implementing the latter for the time being.  At least it will ensure cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The regular `<input type="text">` has [no such limit](http://plea.se/me/cryptimage3.html) and neither should `textarea`. I still recommend `input type=text` because it's, in my experience, much faster than `textarea` to handle a large amount of text.